# How do I check if Property X of a COM object has value Y in C#?

Tags: c#, com, outlook

I'm currently trying to get just the contacts from an Items collection retrieved from Outlook. The problem is that my cast to ContactItem sometimes breaks because there are non-contact items in the list (like distribution lists). Because these are COM objects, I need to check if the property `MessageClass` equals `IPM.Contact`. I'm not familiar with COM objects, so I don't know how to do this. I've tried using the following:

```
if(comObject.GetType().GetProperty(MessageClass).GetValue(comObject).Equals("IPM.Contact"))
{
    contactitems.add((ContactItem)comObject)
}
```

However, this fails because it cannot find the property on the comobject.

Comment: @HansPassant did you even read the website you linked? it says right there in that list that a ContactItem DOES have a MessageClass Property.http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._contactitem.messageclass(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Okay.  Is there any particular reason why you don't just cast *comObject* to _ContactItem?  I suspect the failure is related to this.

Comment: Because the Items collection does not contain only _ContactItem objects, but also, for example, DistList objects. In theory, I could try 'contactItem = comObject as _ContactItem;' and then check for null though.

Comment: Also, I just checked MSDN, and I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx, which explains how to check this programmatically. I'll try that out and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked MSDN, and they suggest at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx to use `object is ContactItem` to check if it's a ContactItem. I've tried this, and it works.